# How to send email within in a loop with SMTP?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-5, smtpclient

I have a console app thats sends mails within a thread.

in this thread method I have a loop that semds emails to each recipient.

I am having issues where as I am trying to send multiple emails before the previous ones have had the chance to get sent.

my code:

```
            foreach(var m in mailModel.Recipients)
            {
                Mailmanager.SendMessageS(mailModel.DomainName, mailModel.Severity, DateTime.Now, m);
            }
```

And the send method:

```
public static async Task SendMessageS(string domainName, ErrorSeverity severity, DateTime errorTime, Recipient recipient)
{

    try
    {
        string error = "";

        string fromEmail = "OwerWatch@mydomain.com";
        string toEmail = recipient.SendEmailTo;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail);
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(server, port);

        /*if (_useAuthentication)*/
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

        //mail.Subject = subject;
        //mail.Body = body;

        message.Subject = "Problem ( " + severity + ") " + domainName;
        message.Body = BuildMessage(error, recipient.RecipientName, domainName, errorTime, severity);

        smtpClient.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;

        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(fromEmail, toEmail, message.Subject, message.Body  /* user state, can be any object*/);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am getting this warrning:

> because this call is not awaited execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await
>   opeartor to the result of the call

I understand the warrning but I can't figure out how I can accomplish this since I have a loop that goes through all my recipients.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick fix (added `await` keyword on your call to `Mailmanager.SendMessageS`), since your utility method is working doing async operation.

```
foreach(var m in mailModel.Recipients)
{
    await Mailmanager.SendMessageS(mailModel.DomainName, mailModel.Severity, DateTime.Now, m);
}
```

There might be better ways to do it as an overall process.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is to use a queue.

You should add all your messages to a queue and than process them one by one, even with multiple threads, if you want.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656977/throttling-speed-of-email-sending-process?rq=1) answer for a couple of examples.